# Case insensitive matching in 'vespa.ai'

Tags: vespa

How to disable casefolding using field-type `string` in vespa.ai?

```
search post {
    document post {
        field token type string {
            indexing: index
            match: word
            rank: filter
            rank-type: empty
            stemming: none
            normalizing: none
            indexing-rewrite: none
        }
    }
}
```

Fill database:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"
    --data-binary '{"fields":{"token":"TeSt"}}'
    http://localhost:8080/document/v1/post/post/docid/TeSt
```

Query matches even case is different (due casefolding):

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    --data '{"yql" : "select * from post where token contains \"test\";"}'
    http://localhost:8080/search/ | jq .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vespa does not support case sensitive search even with match:word.

Answer (score 1):

This is asked every few years but nobody has really actually needed it yet. It is easy to add, feel free to create an issue for it on github.com/vespa-engine/vespa if you really need it.